# Create unit test for method in class using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, methods

I am trying to create a unit test for a method in my file crypto.py. This file runs a webscraper that collects data from cryto.com. I am struggling to understand how to create a unit test for some of the methods if I would like these tests to be in a separate file. For instance, this is the first method in crytpo.py:

```
class Scraper():

    def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    def accept_cookies(self) -> webdriver.Chrome:
       driver = self.driver
       driver.get('https://crypto.com/eea')
       driver.maximize_window()
       time.sleep(3)
       try:
           WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
           time.sleep(3)
       except TimeoutException:
           print('Loading timed out.')
```

As you can see, the accept_cookies method is used to click the "accept cookies" button on the crypto.com homepage. How can I create a unit test IN ANOTHER FILE that will check this method is working.

So far I have created another file crypto_test.py and written the following code:

```
import crypto
import unittest

Crypto = crypto.Scraper() # allows crytpo.py methods to be called and tested

class TestCrypto(unittest.TestCase): 

    def test_accept_cookies(self):
        self.assert(Crypto.accept_cookies)
```

But I don't know how to test the accept cookies function. Any help appreciated (I am also fairly new to python)

Answer (score 0):

To test any method you need to ensure it did what it should. So, you need to check the result of the method.
The main goal of `accept_cookies` method is to get rid of the cookies pop-up. This means you need to ensure the button was clicked. So you need to check if the pop-up (or the button itself) disappeared from the page.
So, your test method will look like that:

```
    def test_accept_cookies(self):
        Crypto.accept_cookies
        try:
            button = WebDriverWait(Crypto.driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")))
        except TimeoutException:
            return
        raise Exception('Cookies pop-up has not disappeared')
```

And you need to import TimeoutException to be able to catch it:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```